# If you use a filler and cover it immediately, will there be any problems?

Tags: hole-repair

If I use cement, concrete, plaster, paste etc and fill a deep wall hole, then cover/seal the visible side with aluminium or some other cover, will it cause any problems for the fill?

I mean once put down will this fillers need air to help them cure and won't the fact that they have some air on the inside of the wall be sufficient?

So in this or any relevant context, can or can I not do the fill then cover it after a few hours with something like aluminum foil?

Thanks.
Thanks.

Comment: Read the directions on the individual fillers.  Everyone is different. If doubt, experiment with small samples.

Comment: Aluminum is HIGHLY incompatible with cement. So don't use that... Is there a cask of Amontillado involved, I have to wonder...?

Comment: If you use a masonry cement and cover it, it will not affect its setting up and curing. It cures by, pardon the term chemical reaction, where water mixes with the properties of Portland cement and hardens, even under water. And yes concrete will eat up aluminum after a time. The lime based product in cement does not like aluminum at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cement, concrete, plaster-of-paris, epoxy:

These two-part fillers set by an internal chemical reaction, not by contact with the air, so you can cover them immediately after placing them with no ill effects.

Paste, oil-based putty, white-glue and sawdust, "mud", no-gaps etc

These fillers set by a reaction with the air, or by evaporation
If you cover them curing time will be extended.